# How to get the json array size inside the component in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working in an angular 6 project , here I need to get the size of the array which comes from the API response .

While inspect the data which I have received from API call ,I can see that the array size is 3 in console .I don't know how to get the array size in a component variable.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.CartdataService.get_Basic_Images().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.get_Carousel_Images = data['1'].filter((img, i) => i !== 0);
        this.slider_Active_Item = data[1][0]['CAROUSEL_IMAGE_PATHS'];
        console.log(data) // how to get the array size here
      });
  }
```

Link : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-carousel-dynamic2-prrges?file=app%2Fone%2Fone.component.ts

Thanks

Comment: `console.log(data.length)`

Comment: got this error [ts] Property 'lenght' does not exist on type 'Object'. @Sanoj_V

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare a property `size: number;`

then edit as **Sanoj_V** said, the function in this way

```
 ngOnInit() {
   this.CartdataService.get_Basic_Images().subscribe(
      (data:any) => {
        this.size= data.length;
        this.get_Carousel_Images = data['1'].filter((img, i) => i !== 0);
        this.slider_Active_Item = data[1][0]['CAROUSEL_IMAGE_PATHS'];
      });
  }
```

now your `size` property has the length.

If you are sure that your data has always a length then it's ok, otherwise you should check if it's define. Something like this, in case :

```
if(!!data.length){
   this.size = data.length;
}
```

Comment: it's working in stackblitz but in project "[ts] Property 'length' does not exist on type 'Object'" got this error

Comment: I could not find length after putting the . after data "data.length" \

Comment: did you put the data:any in the subscription?

Comment: Can you please make a public repo so i can clone it and work on it?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `any` type

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.CartdataService.get_Basic_Images().subscribe(
          (data:any) => {
            this.get_Carousel_Images = data['1'].filter((img, i) => i !== 0);
            this.slider_Active_Item = data[1][0]['CAROUSEL_IMAGE_PATHS'];
            console.log(data.length) // how to get the array size here
          });
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting compile time error then you have to use the object by using this method data['length']

Change your code like this now it compile without any error

```
get_Carousel_Images :string;
slider_Active_Item :string;
  ngOnInit() {
   this.CartdataService.get_Basic_Images().subscribe(
      data => {
console.log(data['length']);
        this.get_Carousel_Images = data['1'].filter((img, i) => i !== 0);
        this.slider_Active_Item = data[1][0]['CAROUSEL_IMAGE_PATHS'];
      });
  }

}
```

Comment: got the output but also I got the error is console as ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

Comment: check this link it is working fine https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-carousel-dynamic2-w7web9

Comment: I checked it already ,it's working there but not in my project

Comment: in your project what kind of data you are getting

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps some typing will help you.
I would create an interface of a single Basic Image and then tell Typescript, that the subscription expects an array of those.

```
interface BasicImages{
// details about one Basic Image
}

this.CartdataService.get_Basic_Images().subscribe(
  (imageList:BasicImages[] => {
    // Do some magic things here
    console.log(imageList.length)
  });
```

This helps you in multiple ways.
It makes the code more readable and the statice code analysis will find some errors at transpile time.